# How to submit or not a form using jquery and javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

i have a form like:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="sub.php" onsubmit="return checkField();">
.
.
.
</form>
```

in head i have:

```
<script>
   function checkField(){
      var fieldToCheck = $('#field').val();
      $.post("checkField.php",{field:fieldTocheck},function(msg)){
         return msg=='ok';
      }
   }
</script>
```

the problem is that form will submit always.. i know that the return inside `$.post` is for function of success and not for function `checkField()` ..  so what can i do? can someone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: first you need to `return false` to stop form from submitting. Then after ajax success , you can submit form by javascript. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 function checkField(){
      var fieldToCheck = $('#field').val();
      $.post("checkField.php",{field:fieldTocheck},function(msg)){
         return msg=='ok';
         // pure js submit() to stop checkField() to be called again
         $('#form')[0].submit();  
      }
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: i think $('#form').submit(); will emit another call to checkField

Answer (score 1):

1st, prevent the submit event:

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}
```

2nd, if all ok, proceed with submission

```
   function checkField(){
      var fieldToCheck = $('#field').val();
      $.post("checkField.php",{field:fieldTocheck},function(msg)){
         $('#form').submit();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified in your form, onsubmit="return checkField();"

But your checkField() returns nothing.

You must return either false to signal abort and don't post, or something else to signify to proceed with the post.

Try this:

```
function checkField(){
  var fieldToCheck = $('#field').val();
  var okToSubmit = false;
  $.post("checkField.php",{field:fieldTocheck},function(msg)){
     if (msg=='ok')
        okToSubmit = true;
  }
  return okToSubmit();
}
```

Also, the post to checkField must be synchronous (async = False), otherwise the checkField() function will return its current value (false) BEFORE checking if the field is correct, thereby giving you false negatives.

Haven't tested:

```
function checkField(){
  return $.post("checkField.php",{field:$('#field').val()},function(msg)){
     return ('ok' == msg);
  }
}
```

(This last form is more awkward - you can't easily add more tests to the first one).

Answer (score 0):

The hardest think is that u have to return some value in ur checkField function before request is processed, so one of the solutions is to return false and post ur form details only on success

```
<script>
function checkField(){
  var fieldToCheck = $('#field').val();
  $.post("checkField.php",{field:fieldTocheck},function(msg){
     if (msg=='ok') 
     {
        var $form = $('#form'),
        par = $form.serialize();
        $.post($form.attr('action'), par, function(){});
     }
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```